# reduce method to change two key names and maintain their position

Tags: javascript

How can I run the reduce method only once to change the two key names and keep this position in the object?
Example of the code

```
const newArrayOfObj = rows.map(row => {
    row = Object.keys(row).reduce(
        (a, key) =>
         ({
            ...a,
            [key === 'redirects' ? 'clicks' : key]: row[key],
        }),
        {},
    );

    row = Object.keys(row).reduce(
        (a, key) =>
         ({
            ...a,
            [key === 'tags' ? 'external impressions' : key]: row[key],
        }),
        {}
    );
    return row;
});
return newArrayOfObj;
```

Comment: There's no way to put keys into a specific position in an object. Non-numeric keys are in the order that they were added to the object.

Comment: Why do you care about the order of keys? When you care about order, you should use arrays, not objects.

Comment: Why do you do them separately in the first place? Put aside that your way to change key names is already clunky.

Comment: I need to use objects, do you see another way to changes the key names without lossing their position? https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-replace-the-names-of-multiple-object-keys-with-the-values-provided-using-javascript/amp/

Comment: There is no guaranteed "position" of keys in object. You need to NOT use object if you want to preserve key orders.

Comment: Even if the implementation of some run time environment does preserve the key order doesn't mean you should take it for granted. Preserving key order is not in the spec so implementation of run time can be changed anytime to mess it up legally.

Comment: Use a proper data structure that suits your need. Or better identify your need: Why do you want to preserve the key order in an object? What is your real goal? You may have fallen into [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.reduce` with most of the iterations just for cloning the object is a waste of processing time. Just simply clone the object, add the new properties, delete the uneccessary properties.

```
const newArrayOfObj = rows.map(row => {
    let newRow = {...row};
    if(newRow.redirects != null)
    {
        newRow.clicks = newRow.redirects;
        delete newRow.redirects;
    }
    if(newRow.tags != null)
    {
        newRow["external impressions"] = newRow.tags
        delete newRow.tags;
    }
    return newRow;
});
return newArrayOfObj;
```

Comment: This will cause the keys to change their position

Comment: keys don't have position